# Merge greywater and graywater tags

Tags: support, status-completed, retagging

I noticed that we have [greywater](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greywater) and [graywater](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graywater). I would vote one of them as a synonym of the other but I don't have enough reputation for that. Can someone please merge the two tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close the loop: this has been done.