# How long to wait before enacting decisions from Meta?

Tags: discussion, moderation, etiquette

In general, how long should we wait for community feedback before confirming and enacting decisions on meta? For example, I recently asked whether we should [burn a tag](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/340/1056) and the response was positive, but [THelper♦ advised patience](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/a/342/1056):

> As a moderator I could already merge the tag, but I'd like to wait a bit to see if there are any people who object to this.

For me personally, having an estimate (at least a rough one) means that I'm more at ease while awaiting community feedback. It also means I'm more likely to revisit the topic later on, and not let it fall into abandon.

#### Precedent

*Tags*

- 1 day [What the difference between the 'urban' and 'city-living' tags?](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33/1056)
- 1 day [Merge greywater and graywater tags](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/101/1056)
- 3 days [Should we merge [car] and [cars]?](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/320/1056)
- 15 days [Heating tag is only for space-heating or not?](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/204/1056)
- 90 days [Disambiguation of the toilet tag?](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/256/1056)

*Site Maintenance*

- 13 days [update the site description](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/260/1056)
- Never [Should we add 'shopping questions and product recommendations' to our Help Center dont-ask list?](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/234/1056)
- Never [Should this site be renamed?](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/186/1056)
- Never [Customising the Help Centre's "What topics can I ask about here?"](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/153/1056)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a discussion becomes a hot meta post (gains at least 3 votes) then it would be reasonable to wait until the discussion is no longer featured as a hot meta post (2 weeks later). It seems fair to assume that most feedback will be provided in the hot period. This exact criteria was [shared by Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130893/137452):

> On sites other than Stack Overflow and sites without per-site metas, if there are still under four items, the rest of the space is filled with hot discussion questions not marked status-completed, **scoring at least 3** and posted **within the past two weeks**. These are picked semi-randomly. (Note that the timing, score and tags can be adjusted per-site to suit the needs of each community).

Of course, this is only a guideline and ultimately it's up to the discretion of the moderators.

Comment: It's indeed up to the moderator to decide how long to wait. If there is no rush and I am not  sure, I prefer to see first if the community agrees before acting. Of course when I am sure I will act immediately (e.g. closing clearly off-topic questions and deleting spam posts). A problem is that we have relatively little participation on meta so waiting for community response doesn't always work, but it doesn't hurt to try.

Comment: Hi Nic, want to mark this as accepted? I think two weeks is a good time-frame.